# Bootstrap modal does not take correct id dynamically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal, slim-lang

I have this code written in ruby on rails and slim. In the code below, I am trying to loop over every lessons I have and display them. Also, each lesson has question button which generates a pop-up box (bootstrap modal) which take the question input, the lesson_id related to that question and saves it into the database. The problem with this code is each question button takes lesson_id of the first lesson only. No matter which lessons's question I click on, it always take the lesson id of first lesson. Now, I think the problem here is bootstrap modal is javascript so it loads after the whole content is loaded so that's why I am getting this error. But I am not sure how do I solve this. Please help me with this problem. Thank you.

```
`-lessons.each do |lesson|
  span.pull-right
    a[data-open="exampleModal2"]
      i.fa.fa-question[aria-hidden="true"]
  #exampleModal2.reveal[data-reveal]
        h1
        center
          | Ask question
        = simple_form_for Question.new, url: lesson_questions_path(lesson.id), method: :post do |f|
          = lesson.name
          = f.input :title, label: "Question"
          = f.input :content, label: "Question Description"
          = f.button :submit
          button.close-button aria-label=("Close modal") data-close="" type="button"
            span aria-hidden="true"  &times;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `id` attribute not being changed after each iteration which leaves you with multiple elements sharing the same id and thus with broken Bootstrap modals and invalid HTML.

You should change this:

```
#exampleModal2.reveal[data-reveal]
```

with something like this:

```
.reveal[data-reveal id=lesson.id]
```

Do not forget to update `a[data-open="exampleModal2"]` correspondingly. I don't remember how Bootstrap opens modals, but if it's via `data-open` attribute, then this should be it.

Comment: This gives me an error saying  `ActionView::Template::Error (Multiple id attributes specified):
`  and the pages does not show anything. Just says something went wrong.

Comment: Then it means you did something like this `#exampleModal2.reveal[data-reveal id=lesson.id]` instead of what I wrote in my answer. Read the error, read the code. It's all in there, you only need to pay attention